# Opening a Child Window When Clicking An Entry Window Is Not Getting Closed

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

a. Have a simple program, where in I wanted to open a child window from main window.
b. I have an open button, when I click that it opens a new window and when I press the close button in the child window it closes the child window.
c. Similarly I wanted the same option in the entry widget.
d. When I click the entry widget to enter something, this should pop-up a child window giving some user tips. 
d. This function opens the child window as expected, but when I click the close button in the child process its not getting closed.

```
#!/tools/bin/python 

from Tkinter import * 
#import Tkinter as tk

class MyFirstGUI:

    cw = None

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("A simple GUI")

        self.label = Label(master, text="This is our first GUI!")
        self.label.pack()

        self.greet_button = Button(master, text="Greet", command=self.greet)
        self.greet_button.pack()

        self.close_button = Button(master, text="Close", command=quit)
        self.close_button.pack()

        self.open_button = Button(master, text="Open", command=self.create_window)
        self.open_button.pack()

        self.scae1 = Entry(root, width=43, bg="yellow")
        self.scae1.delete(0, END)
        self.scae1.insert(0, 'Enter The World')
        self.scae1.bind('<FocusIn>', self.scae1_entry_click)
        self.scae1.pack()


    def greet(self):
        print("Greetings!")

    def create_window(self):
        self.cw = Toplevel()
        self.cw.wm_title("A New Window")
        self.l = Label(self.cw, text="This is window")
        self.l.pack() 

        self.cw_text = Text(self.cw)
        self.cw_text.insert('1.0', "Please Enter the Following")
        self.cw_text.pack()

        self.close_button = Button(self.cw, text="Close", command=self.close_window)
        self.close_button.pack()

    def close_window(self):
        if self.cw:
            try: self.cw.destroy()   
            except (): pass # fill in the error here
            self.cw = None    

    def scae1_entry_click(self,event):
        if (self.scae1):
            if self.scae1.get() == 'Enter The World':
               self.scae1.delete(0, "end") # delete all the text in the entry
               self.scae1.insert(0, '') #Insert blank for user input
               self.scae1.configure(bg="white")
            self.create_window()

root = Tk()
my_gui = MyFirstGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

It would be great if anyone gives some suggestions or comments why this child window is not getting closed when you open it from the entry widget.

Thanks in Adv,
Vimo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow that was a very interesting error. But you have a loop in your logic. So what is happening is, if you close your toplevel-Window the `Entry`-Widget get automaticly the focus. If this happens your binding is triggering again. So just change this line:

```
self.scae1.bind('<FocusIn>', self.scae1_entry_click)
```

to this:

```
self.scae1.bind('<Button-1>', self.scae1_entry_click)
```

Or make sure your Entry loses the focus.

Comment: Thanks VRage.. That worked.. Is it possible to map two options to the same event.. something like,

    self.scae1.bind('<Button-1,Key>', self.scae1_entry_click) ??

Comment: No problem, mark this answer as correct pls. Sure you can use the `bind`method multiple times: `        self.scae1.bind('<Button-1>', self.scae1_entry_click)
        self.scae1.bind('<Key>', self.scae1_entry_click)`